# Why is my Python ircbot stopping at NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname... and won't join a channel?

Tags: python, irc, bots

My irc bot is hanging at :calvino.freenode.net "NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname..." It was working before I added some functions to my code. I've since commented those functions out, but it's still not working!
It stays at that message, doesn't progress. I have to force it to quit.

I'm a very novice coder, I only started to code two weeks or so ago. So it's totally possible that I have a very stupid error there somewhere.
For reference, I used this post to write the framework of my bot. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9363159&postcount=3
I didn't post the rest of my code but I've put it in this pastebin, in case it is needed! http://pastebin.com/kVF04UFr

```
    import socket
    import urllib2
    import httplib
    import mechanize

    channel = '#testbot'
    botnick = 'tastybot'
    network = 'irc.freenode.net'
    port = 6667
    irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
    irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
    print irc.recv ( 4096 )
    irc.send ( 'NICK' + botnick + ':\r\n' )
    irc.send ( 'USER tastybot tastybot tastybot :Python IRC\r\n' )
    irc.send ( 'JOIN' + channel + ':\r\n' )
    irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG' + channel + ':What\'s up?\r\n' )
    running = True

    [various functions]

    while running:
        [rest of code]
```

Comment: Try to install wireshark and capture the traffic to check what's going wrong. I've found this to usually be the best way to check for errors in protocols that it knows. Errors I see here are 1. You forget a space after `NICK`, `JOIN` and `PRIVMSG` and 2. You don't `recv` after the `NICK` and `JOIN` messages, thus possibly sending the following messages too early, so they are ignored by the server.

Comment: By the way, if it helps you, a very simple bot written in Ruby can be found on [my Github page](https://github.com/niklasb/ircstuff/blob/master/ircbot.rb). There's some more necessary stuff in it like automatically responding to `PING`s.

Comment: Do you have an [ident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident) service running?  I've had problems connecting to freenode because I wasn't running an ident service.

Comment: I added spaces after the NICK, etc. Nothing happened, bot still isn't working. I don't understand about the ident service. I don't use an ident myself when connecting to irc using my own client and I can connect fine. Why would it make a difference if my bot is connecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the IRC server you are connecting to requires that an ident is given:

> Ident is an old protocol that servers used to identify which user on a shared system was connecting to them. Nowadays, it is most often used to weed out clones and floodbots from compromised machines (which usually don't have identd [the ident daemon] installed).

Source: http://help.undernet.org/faq.php#19

The easiest fix to this is to try to connect to another IRC-server, you could try 'holmes.freenode.net' as your server. I have had no problems with using my IRC bot on that server.

Edit:
If you want to take a look on the code I am using for connecting to the server: [connection.py](https://github.com/veiset/Brunobot/blob/master/module/core/connection.py)

Comment: Running an ident seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is your error but you seem to have a problem with your string here:

```
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG' + channel + ':What's up?\r\n' )
```

your apostrophe for what's is making the program think that it has exited the string

Comment: It's not that. I'm not sure where it went but I have irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG' + channel + ':What\'s up?\r\n' ) , so python doesn't get upset at the apostrophe in 'What's'

Answer (score 0):

You forgot spaces at sending. Should be like that:

```
import socket
import urllib2
import httplib
import mechanize

channel = '#testbot'
botnick = 'tastybot'
botuser = 'tastybot'
network = 'irc.freenode.net'
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
print irc.recv ( 4096 )
irc.send ( 'NICK ' + botnick + '\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'USER ' + botuser + ' 0 * :Python IRC\r\n' ) # Read RFC next time, please
irc.send ( 'JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :What\'s up?\r\n' )
running = True

[various functions]

while running:
    [rest of code]
```

If account uses password, just send `PASS password` as FIRST message - before sending username and nickname - right after establishing connection.

Also in IRC (as defined by RFC) max message len is 512 bytes.

BTW you should really stop reading frame when last 2 symbols in received strings are `\r\n`. Sample in my bot (hy-powered):

```
  (defn read [self]
    (setv b 512)
    (setv on True)
    (setv c "")
    (while (and on (!= b 0))
      (setv x (self.sock.recv 1))
      (+= c (x.decode "UTF-8"))
      (-= b 1)
      (if (= "\r\n" (cut c -2))
        (do
          (if (= "" (cut c -2))
            (continue))
          (setv on False)
          (setv c (cut c 0 -2)))))
    c)
```